# ApplicationContext for Test environment using TestContainer in Micronaut application not working

Tags: java, junit, junit5, micronaut, testcontainers

I am trying to test the Micronaut application using MongoDb and RabbitMQ test containers. The `application.yml` has the below configuration

```
mongodb:
  uri: "mongodb://${MONGO_HOST:localhost}:${MONGO_PORT:27017}"
  database: "FeteBird-Product"
```

I have the below code for the configuration

```
@Introspected
@ConfigurationProperties("mongodb")
public record MongodbConfiguration(@NotNull String uri, @NotNull String database) {
}
```

In the repository. The repository is in another project

```
@Singleton
    public record Repository(MongoClient mongoClient, MongodbConfiguration mongodbConfiguration) implements IRepository {
    @Override
    public <T> MongoCollection<T> getCollection(String collectionName, Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        return mongoClient
                .getDatabase(mongodbConfiguration.database())
                .getCollection(collectionName, typeParameterClass);
    }
}
```

`mongodbConfiguration.uri` is always `mongodb://localhost:27017`, however in the JUnit testing I have the below code

```
@Testcontainers
public abstract class TestContainerFixture {
    public static final GenericContainer mongoDBContainer;
    public static final GenericContainer rabbitMQContainer;

    static {
        mongoDBContainer = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.0.10")).withExposedPorts(27017);
        rabbitMQContainer = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("rabbitmq:3-management-alpine")).withExposedPorts(5672);
        mongoDBContainer.start();
        rabbitMQContainer.start();
    }
}

@MicronautTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class DiscountDeleteListenerTest extends TestContainerFixture {
    
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@BeforeAll
@DisplayName("Initial application setup")
void initialApplicationSetup() {
    applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run(
            Map.of("mongodb.uri",
                    String.format("mongodb://%s:%s", mongoDBContainer.getContainerIpAddress(), mongoDBContainer.getMappedPort(27017)),
                    "rabbitmq.uri",
                    String.format("amqp://%s:%s", rabbitMQContainer.getContainerIpAddress(), rabbitMQContainer.getMappedPort(5672)))
            , "test"
    );
    iDiscountProducer = applicationContext.getBean(IDiscountProducer.class);
}
}
```

The below code is fine

```
String.format("mongodb://%s:%s", mongoDBContainer.getContainerIpAddress(), mongoDBContainer.getMappedPort(27017))
```

This gives the URL as `mongodb://localhost:57032`

Now when I finish all the unit tests and check the database it is inserting, updating, and deleting from the local docker instance that is port 27017

The host for the cluster is still pointing to 27017

[image]

Got some idea from here https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-test/issues/32 but still quite not sure how to do it.

Comment: maybe a casuality but right now I'm in the same situation and I think is because we cant use MicronautTest and TestContainer at the same time. When you annotate the test with MicronautTest it wake up the application before to call your initialization method, but it's only a suposition

Comment: not sure about Micronaut, but if it uses default auto-config, then you need to exclude MongoAutoConfiguration and create a mongo client manually, otherwise it will point to the default configured MongoDB

Answer (score -1):

we cant use MicronautTest and TestContainer at the same time. When you annotate the test with MicronautTest it wake up the application before to call your initialization method

So removing the `@MicronautTest` solve the issue

Comment: Any update answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71882930/overriding-configuration-properties-with-test-container-in-micronaut-not-working/71883180#71883180