# Overriding Configuration properties with test container in Micronaut not working

Tags: java, micronaut, testcontainers, micronaut-test

Test container configuration

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Testcontainers
public abstract class TestContainerFixture {
    @Container
    protected static final GenericContainer mongoDBContainer;
    protected static final Map<String, Object> properties;

    static {
        mongoDBContainer = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.0.10"))
                .withExposedPorts(27017)
                .withReuse(true);
        mongoDBContainer.start();
        properties = Map.of("mongodb.uri",
                String.format("mongodb://%s:%s/FeteBird-Product",
                        mongoDBContainer.getContainerIpAddress(),
                        mongoDBContainer.getMappedPort(27017)));
    }

    protected static ApplicationContext applicationContext;
}
```

**Application.yml**

```
mongodb:
  uri: "mongodb://${MONGO_HOST:localhost}:${MONGO_PORT:27017}/FeteBird-Product"
  database: "FeteBird-Product"
```

JUnit Testing

```
@MicronautTest(rebuildContext = true)
public class SubCategoryCreateTest extends TestContainerFixture {
    @BeforeAll
    public static void initUnitTest() {
        applicationContext = ApplicationContext.run(properties, ConstantValues.TEST_ENVIRONMENT);
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should create sub category with valid claim as Owner")
    void shouldCreateSubCategoryWithValidClaimAsOwner() {

        // Given
        HttpResponse<CategoryModel> categoryrsp = this.httpRequestToCreateCategory();
        assertEquals(categoryrsp.getStatus(), HttpStatus.CREATED);

        // When
        SubCategoryModel subCategoryModel = new SubCategoryModel(null, "Men swim sweat", "Men swim seat description");
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.POST(String.format("%s/%s/%s", "category", categoryrsp.body().id(), "/sub-category"), subCategoryModel)
                .bearerAuth(bearerAccessRefreshToken.getAccessToken());
        HttpResponse<SubCategoryModel> rsp = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, SubCategoryModel.class);
        var item = rsp.body();

        // Then
        assertEquals(rsp.getStatus(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        assertTrue(item.id() != null);
    }
}
```

The configuration is not over-ridden in the service layer, Controller has the dependency on service layer

[image]

**Update after implementing TestPropertyProvider works**

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Testcontainers
public class TestContainerFixture implements TestPropertyProvider {
    protected GenericContainer mongoDBContainer;

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        mongoDBContainer = new GenericContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.0.10"))
                .withExposedPorts(27017)
                .withReuse(true);
        mongoDBContainer.start();
         return Map.of("mongodb.uri",
                        String.format("mongodb://%s:%s/FeteBird-Product",
                                mongoDBContainer.getContainerIpAddress(),
                                mongoDBContainer.getMappedPort(27017)));
    }
}

@MicronautTest
public class SubCategoryCreateTest extends TestPropertyProvider {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should create sub category with valid claim as Owner")
    void shouldCreateSubCategoryWithValidClaimAsOwner() {

        // Given
        HttpResponse<CategoryModel> categoryrsp = this.httpRequestToCreateCategory();
        assertEquals(categoryrsp.getStatus(), HttpStatus.CREATED);

        // When
        SubCategoryModel subCategoryModel = new SubCategoryModel(null, "Men swim sweat", "Men swim seat description");
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.POST(String.format("%s/%s/%s", "category", categoryrsp.body().id(), "/sub-category"), subCategoryModel)
                .bearerAuth(bearerAccessRefreshToken.getAccessToken());
        HttpResponse<SubCategoryModel> rsp = client.toBlocking().exchange(request, SubCategoryModel.class);
        var item = rsp.body();

        // Then
        assertEquals(rsp.getStatus(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        assertTrue(item.id() != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement `TestPropertyProvider` and set up your database URL in the `getProperties` method that it requires

See the [guide here](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-mongodb-synchronous-gradle-java.html#test) for an example

Comment: Well the configuration is working however, the container resue is not working .withReuse(true); Added the updated code on the update section. Please can you let me know what I am missing